# Having trouble with an if statement with an or statement embedded in a for loop

Tags: python, for-loop

```
random_characters = "adak"

for letter in random_characters:
    print(letter)
    if letter == "a":
        print("Vowel")
```

...emits as output:

```
a
Vowel
d
a
Vowel
k
```

If I only include one letter in the if statement the code runs fine. However, If I add one more through an or statement...

```
a
Vowel
d
Vowel
a
Vowel
k
Vowel
```

"Vowel" is printed after every iteration.

Comment: please edit the question and show the failing example

Comment: Note that we're a Q&A database, not a message forum. Please try to write your question  like what you'd see as a FAQ entry, instead of as a conversation.

Comment: That said, you really need to show us the code that _fails_, not the code that works. I assume you're writing `letter == "a" or "e"`, and that's a clear problem, but we shouldn't have to assume.

Comment: Please update your question title. There is nothing in the current title that summarizes the problem.

Comment: It'd also be useful to know what you change to make the code fail, since that's the crux of the issue.

Comment: I didn't expect such fast results but ok I'll try to meet your requests.

Comment: Your best bet for an updated Python test on whether a particular character is one of a set of qualifying characters is something like `if letter in "aeiou":`

Comment: BTW, you can put downvotes and close votes on hold by temporarily deleting your question, and then undeleting it when you're done editing. (At least, you can do that _before it's answered_; when @timroberts added an answer to the question, he also may have limited your ability as a low-rep user to unilaterally delete).

Comment: Thanks Joffan thats a way more condensed way of doing what I did fantastic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to read between the lines and guess that you have made the very common mistake of writing:

```
    if letter == "a" or "e":
```

because that would produce the results you see.  The reason is, that is interpreted as

```
    if (letter == "a")  or  "e":
```

and since "e" is always True, the `if` is always taken.  If you want to compare to multiple letters, use `in`:

```
    if letter in ("a","e","i","o","u"):
```

although in this case, you could also write:

```
    if letter in "aeiuo":
```

Comment: Why re-answer something for which we have several canonical duplicates already?